# Animating -webkit-clip-path using jQuery or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

at the moment I'm trying to use CSS animations to clip images when the user hovers over them. However, when moving from one image to the next because the images are clipped and the animation always starts at a specific keyframe, the animation looks jagged. I thought using the current value of the clip-path and animating it to the end position is a possible solution but that doesn't seem possible with just CSS. However, when I try to animate the clip-path using jQuery, it doesn't do it, and I'm not sure whether it's supported or not.

Does anyone have any advice?

Some of the animations are as follows and as they don't have the same 0% keyframe, the image jumps to 0% and animates from there.

```
@-webkit-keyframes "animation"
{
0%
{
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%,100% 0%,75% 100%,0% 100%);
}

100%
{
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 100%,0% 100%);
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes "animation2"
{
0%
{
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 100%,0% 100%);
}

100%
{
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%,100% 0%,75% 100%,0% 100%);
}
}
```

Thanks.